# Let f the function f, if x is rational so f equal 1, if x is a irational so f iqual zero. Show that funcion is not integrable.Please,i need understand

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let f the function f, if x is rational so f equal 1, if x is a irational so f equal zero.
Show that funcion is not riemann integrable in intervall [0,1].

I have the answer, but i dont understand, i need to explication.The proof is
Let $0=<x_0<x_1...<x_{i-1},x_i....<x_n=1$ the any partition in [0,1].If c_1,....,c_n be rational so
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(c_i)\Delta x_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Delta x_i=1$

If c_1,....,c_n be irational so
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(c_i)\Delta x_i=0$

Comment: what your attempt and describe where you get stuck. As of now, your question might be closed.

Comment: What criteria do you know that makes a function Riemann integrable?